# Why might the O—H stretch in the IR of MY triphenylmethanol product be less intense than expected?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, teaching-lab

Why might the O—H stretch in the IR of MY triphenylmethanol product be less intense than expected when compared to the expected IR for triphenylmethanol?

I'm interpreting the IR I took of my product, triphenylmethanol, to the expected IR I obtained from SDBS.

My IR: [image: my triphenylmethanol product]

SDBS: [image: SDBS triphenylmethanol IR]

We performed a Grignard Reaction in lab using bromobenzene and methyl benzoate in order to synthesize triphenylmethanol.

ANY clues why my triphenylmethanol (O—H stretch) is not as intense? I really don't know.

Comment: is your ir instrument properly calibrated? If not that might explain your results

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation would be the concentration of sample you used. Of course, if you are confident that you had utilized sufficient concentration then there may be another reason for the decreased intensity. However, some of the other peaks are also somewhat decreased in intensity so it is a possibility.

This point is noted here (http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Spectroscopy/Infrared_Spectroscopy/Infrared%3A_Interpretation#The_Origin_of_Peak_Intensities)